# Why I am getting android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException with AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, networkonmainthread

I am getting android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException while I have wrote the code of networking operation in AsynkTask. is there any other reason for throwing this exception?

**Here is my Code:**

```
public class Background_confirmation extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Confirmation.this,
                    "Please wait...", "Retrieving data ...", true);
            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                        "http://68.121.167.160/sip_chat_api/create_account.php?useralias="
                                + useralias + "&cntname=" + cntcode + "");
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    is = entity.getContent();


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (backgroung_flag == 1) {

            } else {
                if (is != null) {
                    try {
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        String line = null;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line + "\n");
                        }
                        is.close();

                        result = sb.toString();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("log_tag",
                                "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                    }
                }

            }
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                // progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            }
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }
```

And i am calling this class in OnCreate()

```
new Background_confirmation().execute();
```

But it always goes in Catch block and gives me [this](http://pastie.org/4601772) exceptions [LogCat](http://pastie.org/4601772)
Any suggestion and idea will be Appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Check out Android Query for these Async Tasks, simplifies it all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class Background_confirmation extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Confirmation.this, "Please wait...", "Retrieving data ...", true);

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://68.121.167.160/sip_chat_api/create_account.php?useralias=" + useralias + "&cntname=" + cntcode + "");
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (backgroung_flag == 1) {

            } else {
                if (is != null) {
                    try {
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        String line = null;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line + "\n");
                        }
                        is.close();

                        result = sb.toString();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                // progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Your code should change like above. Things you have to consider

- Connectivity should code inside `doInBackground()`
- If you want to get the result of the `doInBackground()`, you have to take it in `onPostExecute()`
- That means you have to return a String value in `doInBackground()` where your third parameter of `AsyncTask` class should be String too (which is not in Wayne's answer)

In your code, you are calling a `InputStream` that we cannot see except in the "else" part. If you are using only that `InputStream`, make sure code always reach the else part.

Comment: Thanks it worked Awesome ! If i use Dipak Keshariya's code to disable the strictMode Policy then will it slow down the performance of my Application? Because while disabling StrictMode it shows lots of line in log.What's is your opinion>

Comment: That is normal to show lots of coding while using `StrictMode`. To check the performance at runtime for certain extent you can use **Heap**, **Allocation Tracker** like views in **DDMS** mode in your Eclipse.

Answer (score 5):

You've used wrong AsyncTask method to place Your network related code. Please, move it to `doInBackground`, because `onPreExecute` takes place on main thread. So, exception occurred. Details are [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: Thanks for response but if i put the code in doInBackground() then i am not getting the desired result

Comment: what do you mean by 'desired result'?

Answer (score 3):

Put all your network request code in `doInBackground`. 
`onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` will run on UI Thread (main thead) so you will get an exeption if you request network on these 2 methods.

```
public class Background_confirmation extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {            
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Confirmation.this,
                "Please wait...", "Retrieving data ...", true);            

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                    "http://68.121.167.160/sip_chat_api/create_account.php?useralias="
                            + useralias + "&cntname=" + cntcode + "");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (backgroung_flag == 1) {

        } else {
            if (is != null) {
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    is.close();

                    result = sb.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("log_tag",
                            "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                }
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            // progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        }

    }

}
```