# Synchronous API Call Via Android/Java

Tags: java, android

Does anyone know  how I can make a synchronous call via android?  I basically do not want to continue any further until I get the response back y/n from the server.

This is the simplest version of the code that I have

```
URL url = new URL("http://google.com");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) 
url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();
int code = connection.getResponseCode();
```

But it gives me this error because it is created on the main thread.

```
NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: you can not block the main thread....

Comment: Suggestion: You can use Asyntask show a progress bar till u get response. Based on response u can handle what you want to do in onPostExecute https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: I agree, the duplicated question ... didn't have a real answer.

Comment: You can take [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153762/why-i-am-getting-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception-with-asynctask) as an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you can **not** do HTTP calls on MainThread.

There are many way arounds like Create a Runnable thread or AsyncTask etc. Try the following code snippet:

```
new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
              //your HTTP request code..      
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                //Handle exceptions
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

For further reading multithreading see the Android Developer [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/index.html).

Comment: @GhostCat I did'nt quite get you..This code will be a guideline for OP.Rest things OP should handle.It's just a hint or reference

Comment: From what i read, I am forced to create a thread. so what is wrong with @akshay response?  Also the answer you provided is in turkish, I dont talk turkey, well not usually anways.

Comment: Much better now. I took the freedom and slightly updated your answer. And: consider deleting no longer required comments. In case you want to say thank you, I guess you know where to find my answers or questions ;-)

Comment: @flashc5 Correct. Now things look much better.